# Rebuilding an unstable tool from scratch (Currently Access based - can go anywhere)

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, sharepoint, toad

I have inherited a custom built tool that is poorly designed and unstable, and I have a great opportunity to rebuild it from scratch. This is an internal tool only that works almost entirely in Access, and its purpose is to provide higher detail on parts that cost the company over a certain dollar amount.

How it works:

1)  The raw data (new part numbers) gets pulled nightly from the EDW via macros in Access.

2)  The same macros then join two tables (part numbers from one, names from another). Any part under a certain dollar amount is removed, and the new data is appended to the existing Access database.

3)  During the day employees can then open a custom Access form to add more details about the part. Different questions are asked depending on the part category.

4)  The completed form is forwarded to management, and the information entered is retained in the Access database – it does not write back to the EDW.

5)  Managers can also pull some basic reports from the database, based on overall costs.

The problems:

1)  Currently everyone has to have Access installed on their work stations, and whenever there is an update the new database gets pushed to their stations. This is not considered an ideal situation by management or IT.

2)  If anyone has left the tool open accidentally at the end of the day the database is locked out, therefore the macros cannot run and the tool cannot be updated with new part numbers.

3)  If the tool cannot update for a few days in a row the database can become corrupted. We can restore from the last good backup, in the past this has resulted in the loss of multiple days of work.

Ideally we want to take the tool completely out of Access. I am building a SharePoint site that can host the tool, which (if I can get it right) will eliminate the need of Access on end-user stations with a database push. However the SharePoint form would need read/write ability.

The big question is: How do I build this?

I have a completely open path of possibilities – I can design it work any way I want, using any tools or platform I want, as long as it works. It does not have to update automatically, as I already run a number of SQL scripts at the start of my day and adding one more is inconsequential.

The resources I have at my immediate disposal are: SharePoint (with designer), Access, Toad, and SQL Server. The database can be hosted on a shared network drive.

I am a recent college graduate with basic SQL knowledge. I have about a year to produce a final product, but would like to get it up and running far sooner if possible.

Any advice on what direction to pursue would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I've never worked with SQL Server, so I don't know all of it's capabilities (I'm an Oracle developer).

What I'd do in your situation is something like the following (although not necessarily in this exact order):

1. Get a SQL Server database set up to host your tables.
2. Create the tables etc
3. Migrate test data across (I'm assuming you have a dev/uat/test environment for your current system! If you haven't, make sure you set up at least a separate test environment to prod for your new db!)
4. Write stored procs to do the work for adding new parts, updating existing data, etc etc
5. Set up an automated job on the db (I'm assuming SQL Server can do this!) to do the overnight processing.
6. Create a separate db user with the necessary permissions to call the stored procedures
7. Get your frontend to call the stored procs with the relevant parameters using the db user you created in step 6 to connect to the db.

You'd also have to think about transaction control to try and mitigate the case where users go home at the end of the day without committing their work - Does the db handle the commits/rollbacks or does Sharepoint?

Once you've worked out everything in your test environment, it's then a case of creating the prod db, users and objects, and then working out the best way of migrating the prod data across.

Good luck.

Don't forget to get backups for the new db set up as well.

Comment: Good list, short and to the point.  I can confirm that MS SQL does indeed have the tools that are required to run automated tasks.  The only think that I'd add is the necessity for a very thorough planning or discovery phase.  Make sure you are 100% positive how the business processes work, and if not include someone on the project who does. You don't want to have to redo a week or months worth of work because you guessed at a process.

Comment: @Gene definitely agree re planning/design phase! Also, I should have added testing to the list. Extensive testing, especially the edge cases. (I've been involved in a couple of db+server upgrade/migrations, and it was only the extremely thorough testing my whole team did that caught all the bugs, although we were fortunate we could run in parallel and perform comparisons against the prod reports to make sure they matched.)